# How to add new item in Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to add a new item to my list, I use firebase without user(email,password)

I want to add new items like this:-

Start with:

```
-vdjs43ndjufd87
     "name" : Jak
     "university" : Harvard
```

End with:

```
-vdjs43ndjufd87
      "name" : Jak
      "university" : Harvard
      "age" : 23
```

this code is not working with me:-

```
let key = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId().key


let post = ["uid": userID,
        "author": username,
        "title": title,
        "body": body]

let childUpdates = ["/posts/\(key)": post,
                "/user-posts/\(userID)/\(key)/": post]

ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "this code is not working with me"?  Are you receiving any errors?   Also, what do you have `ref` defined as? Are you sure you are defining `ref` before your `ref.updateChildValues(childUpdates)` call?  Your variables in your examples (`name`, `university`, and `age`) do not match that of your code (`uid`, `author`, `title`, `body).. it appears your code is a direct copy-paste from the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write).  Please post your own attempt based on the variable you list in your example.

Comment: My app is airport rating and you can add new Rating without  login

Comment: this what i can't do

Answer (score 1):

ChildByAutoId() should be used to create the key for a *new* node. You already know the node you want to add the data too.

Also, update should be used to change the value of an existing node. The data you are adding doesn't exist yet. (update can also add data but thats another use-case)

Just write the data directly.

```
let ageRef = ref.child("posts").child("-vdjs43ndjufd87").child("age")
ageRef.setValue(23)
```

If you want to create a new node, then use childByAutoId

```
let postRef = ref.child("posts").childByAutoId()
postRef.child("name").setValue("some name")
postRef.child("age").setValue(44)
```

results in

```
-Yie5jas8dj8asdjs
   name: "some name"
   age: 44
```

Comment: @fewa I don't understand the comment. My answer shows you how to update an existing node, where you know the key, or create a new node with child data. Is there something else? If so, can you clarify the question?

Comment: i don't know the key

Comment: @fewa So how would you determine which node you want to update. For example, say there's 10 posts... how would you know which post you want to age an *age* key: value pair to?

Comment: from detail page?

Comment: @fewa There is no mention of a detail page in your question so I don't know what that is. I am asking how you know which node you want to add a child to. If there are three posts; post_0, post_1 and post_2 and you want to add a child value, which post do you want to add it to? i.e. what are the requirements that determine which node has the child added to is?

Comment: This is my question I can not add a new item because I do not know how I can identify the node, I'm sorry if my question incorrect.

Comment: @fewa I can help with the code but I cannot read your mind. Please explain what the process is to determine which node you want to add the new item to; is because you want to add an age node to all females over 50? Do you want to add a age node to all people that are 23? Do you want to add an age node to all users that go to Harvard? What's the purpose of the age node and what's the *criteria* of adding it?